# Hygieia Jenkins-Build Collector not starting with UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring, jenkins, hygieia

I am having a problem getting the Jenkins-build collector working. I am using the latest hygieia-core and latest hygieia-build-jenkins-collector. I can get the rally, sonar, and github collectors running fine as well as a custom collector that I have built. I am on a Mac (locally run with no containers for now) and am building and running the collector with the following commands. Again, I have gotten the other collectors working in the same way.

`mvn clean install package -q`

`java -jar ~/Sandbox/hygieia-dashboard/collectors/build/jenkins/target/jenkins-build-collector.jar --spring.config.name=jenkins --spring.config.location=/Users/[my username]/Sandbox/hygieia-dashboard/collectors/build/jenkins/application.properties`

Here is my **application.properties** file.

```
dbname=dashboarddb

# Database HostName - default is localhost
dbhost=localhost

# Database Port - default is 27017
dbport=27018

# MongoDB replicaset
dbreplicaset=false
#dbhostport=[host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3]

# Database Username - default is blank
dbusername=dashboarduser

# Database Password - default is blank
dbpassword=dbpassword

# Collector schedule (required)
jenkins.cron=0 0/2 * * * *

# The page size
jenkins.pageSize=1000

# The folder depth - default is 10
jenkins.folderDepth=10

# Jenkins server (required) - Can provide multiple
jenkins.servers[0]=[my jenkins url]

# If using username/token for API authentication
# (required for Cloudbees Jenkins Ops Center) For example,
jenkins.servers[1]=http://[username]:[api-token]@[my jenkins url]

# Another option: If using same username/password Jenkins auth,
# set username/apiKey to use HTTP Basic Auth (blank=no auth)
jenkins.usernames[0]=[username]
jenkins.apiKeys[0]=[api-token]

# Determines if build console log is collected - defaults to false
jenkins.saveLog=true

# Search criteria enabled via properties (max search criteria = 2)
jenkins.searchFields[0]= options.jobName
jenkins.searchFields[1]= niceName

# Timeout values
jenkins.connectTimeout=20000
jenkins.readTimeout=20000
```

Below is my **output**. I added where the error is shown when it attempts to start, but let me know if you would like the whole thing.

```
2019-11-13 14:35:37,756 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hudsonCollectorTask' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/anderja1/Sandbox/hygieia-dashboard/collectors/build/jenkins/target/jenkins-build-collector.jar!/com/capitalone/dashboard/collector/HudsonCollectorTask.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 4 of type [com.capitalone.dashboard.repository.CollItemConfigHistoryRepository]: No qualifying bean of type [com.capitalone.dashboard.repository.CollItemConfigHistoryRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: collItemConfigHistoryRepository,sonarProfileRepostory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.capitalone.dashboard.repository.CollItemConfigHistoryRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: collItemConfigHistoryRepository,sonarProfileRepostory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.capitalone.dashboard.Application.main(Application.java:16) [jenkins-build-collector.jar!/:3.1.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [jenkins-build-collector.jar!/:3.1.2-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:819) [na:1.8.0_232]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.capitalone.dashboard.repository.CollItemConfigHistoryRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: collItemConfigHistoryRepository,sonarProfileRepostory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:819)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hudsonCollectorTask' defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/anderja1/Sandbox/hygieia-dashboard/collectors/build/jenkins/target/jenkins-build-collector.jar!/com/capitalone/dashboard/collector/HudsonCollectorTask.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 4 of type [com.capitalone.dashboard.repository.CollItemConfigHistoryRepository]: No qualifying bean of type [com.capitalone.dashboard.repository.CollItemConfigHistoryRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: collItemConfigHistoryRepository,sonarProfileRepostory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.capitalone.dashboard.repository.CollItemConfigHistoryRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: collItemConfigHistoryRepository,sonarProfileRepostory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101)
    at com.capitalone.dashboard.Application.main(Application.java:16)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.capitalone.dashboard.repository.CollItemConfigHistoryRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: collItemConfigHistoryRepository,sonarProfileRepostory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 24 more
```

Unless this collector works differently than the others, I can't see anything that I may be doing wrong, but I could very well be overlooking something. Let me know if you would like any more information regarding this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figured out the issue. I filed an issue with the build-jenkins-collector for Hygieia. It was labeled as a bug so hopefully, it can be fixed soon. The issue can be tracked here: https://github.com/Hygieia/hygieia-build-jenkins-collector/issues/20

In short, I commented out all of the code located at `src/main/java/com/capitalone/dashboard/repository/SonarProfileRepostory.java`

I'm not sure what use the code has, but the sonar and Jenkins build collector work without it just fine and the mentioned errors go away.